# ArrowInvalid: Could not convert <POINT (266000 4016000)> with type Point: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type

Tags: python, pyspark, geopandas, pyarrow

I have a `sparkdataframe` which I converted to pandas-on-spark `dataframe` using `pandas_api()` but when I run the code.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame
model_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_new,
    crs=sweden_gdf.crs,
    geometry=df_new.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x']*1000, row['y']*1000), axis=1)
```

I get this error

```
ArrowInvalid: Could not convert <POINT (266000 4016000)> with type Point: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately spark dataframes don't work with complex data types such as shapely geometries, so you would have to convert it to a pandas dataframe, then to a geodataframe, then do all your geometric calculations and then convert it back to a spark dataframe.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("YourAppName").getOrCreate()

# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
df_new_pd = df_new.toPandas()

# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame
# Adjust the projection system (CRS) as per your requirements
model_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_new_pd,
    crs=sweden_gdf.crs,  # Assuming sweden_gdf is already defined with a CRS
    geometry=df_new_pd.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x']*1000, row['y']*1000), 
axis=1)
)

# Perform your geometric calculations here on model_gdf

# Once calculations are done, convert GeoDataFrame back to Pandas DataFrame
result_pd = pd.DataFrame(model_gdf.drop(columns='geometry'))

# Convert Pandas DataFrame back to Spark DataFrame
result_df = spark.createDataFrame(result_pd)
```